# Installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS next to Windows 10. GRUB shows blackscreen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

Hello AskUbuntu Community
I have an annoying problem with my dual boot on my PC.

I have a solid-state drive (SSD) with Windows 10 on it and another one with ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

When I spam my F8 key to show the boot screen, I can boot Windows 10 without any problems. But when I try to boot Ubuntu, I get a black screen, but it should start GRUB in my opinion.

With Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS it worked very well.

I don't know what I did wrong.

Yours sincerely.

Comment: you need to spam your `F8` key to see the GRUB? Why don't you disable the *Fastboot mode* in the BIOS?

Comment: No, I don't need to spam 'F8'. It's just that I can select the bootdrive. If I select ubuntu, I get a blackscreen aswell.